# Android Studio Download Manager Redirection

Tags: java, android, authentication, redirect, android-download-manager

For easy explain let's just skip a few concepts. Let's say that I have skript which somehow gives file bytes. But to run that script it is necesary to be logged. So I have second script to login automaticly doesn't matter how. This second script after login redirect to first script which should download file. And in web browser it does. But when I am using android studio DownloadManager in mobile app the downloaded file is login page. It seems like redirecting in DownloadManager doesn't keep information. I would be greatful for any given concepts.

Login is for sure good. I tried print data with acces only for logged user, so when i commented redirect command from my script i saw that data. So somehow redirecting loses info about login in DownloadManager

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.